# How can I use std::chrono::duration as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, c++-chrono

I have a template class, something like:

```
template < typename T, size_t Seconds > class MyClass {}
```

Now, I would like to change Seconds to be a duration, so the class can be parametrized with `std::chrono::duration`. For example, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
MyClass < std::string, std::chrono::seconds(30) > object;
```

Also, in the template, I'd like to specify a default value, something like `std::chrono::seconds(30)`.

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer below, it looks like a solid answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can design your template in a clever way:

```
template < typename T, typename Duration = std::chrono::seconds, int duration_value = 30 > 
class MyClass 
{
    // Now you can use duration here:
    // auto duration = Duration(duration_value);
};
```

And then you can instantiate your template as

```
MyClass < std::string, std::chrono::seconds, 30 > object;
```

Or, actually having these values as defaults, simply

```
MyClass < std::string > object;
```

**Edit:**

Taking into account *PaperBirdMaster*'s request, you can limit template's `Duration` type, to be `std::chrono::duration` only, this way:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_chrono_duration
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename Rep, typename Period>
struct is_chrono_duration<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template < typename T, typename Duration = std::chrono::seconds, int duration_value = 30 >
class MyClass
{
    static_assert(is_chrono_duration<Duration>::value, "duration must be a std::chrono::duration");
    // Now you can use duration here:
    // auto duration = Duration(duration_value);
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    MyClass < std::string, std::chrono::seconds, 1> obj1;       // Ok
    MyClass < std::string, std::chrono::milliseconds, 1> obj2;  // Ok
    MyClass < std::string, int, 1> obj3;                        // Error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This allows to instantiate `MyClass` with anything that isn't a chrono value, for example: `MyClass<float, double>`, is it the expected behaviour? Shouldn't it be better to limit the second parameter to chrono types?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster your logic can also be applied for example to `std::remove_if`. What if someone specifies something unexpected instead of `UnaryPredicate p` if instead of iterators? The answer is simple: it won't compile.

Comment: we don't know the logic inside `MyClass`, maybe it will compile with `double` or `my_fancy_class` or wathever with the appropiate operators and it could not be the expected behaviour... anyway, the question was about parametrizing the class with `std::chrono::duration` not with anything that behaves or resembles a `std::chrono::duration`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Then write a `is_duration` trait and do a `static_assert`. It's straightforward.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, yes, that's why concepts are coming. My point was: currently, even standard library does not set any constraints. It's a spirit of template. What if I want to design my own analogue of `std::chrono::duration` and use it as template argument?

Comment: @GreenScape Sorry if I was misunderstood, I didn't said that your solution was wrong, I was saying that without knowing more about `MyClass` we don't know if instantiating the class with a type different of duration is expected or unexpected, so I think that your answer could be more accurate if you ADD a part explaining how to limit the `typename Duration` to a chrono family of types.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, no, excuse me for misunderstanding. I've edited my answer as you suggested.