# Accept Template of Child Class as Template for Object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In the bellow example, using the std::chrono library, I am looking for a means to accept a type of duration for a basic timer.

```
template <std::chrono::duration D> //Accept either std::chrono::minute, second, etc...
class myTimer{


}
```

However, this will not work as Duration doesn't match the criteria of the template keyword.

```
template <class T>
class myTimer{

   //I could do a static cast, but Duration is only a template used by the children, not an actual class per say. 

}
```

So my question boils down to, what would the best solution be for less code and better usability? I feel like a static cast with a unknown child from a template wouldn't work well, but I may be completely wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use std::chrono::duration as a template parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875853/how-can-i-use-stdchronoduration-as-a-template-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of options here, ranging from easy-and-not-quite-as-flexible, to extremely-flexible-but-more-work.

The easiest thing is to just store `nanoseconds`, and not template `myTimer` at all:

```
class myTimer
{
    std::chrono::nanoseconds time_;
    ...
};
```

Your constructor can just take `nanoseconds`.  All of the "built-in" chrono units will implicitly convert to `nanoseconds`:

```
myTimer t{3min};  // ok, 180'000'000'000ns
```

The only disadvantage here is that not *every* `duration` will implicitly convert to `nanoseconds`.  Perhaps you want your clients to be able to use picoseconds, 1/60s units, or floating-point durations, or perhaps the intent here (it's hard to tell) is to control the precision of the storage inside the timer (not really necessary, but you never know).  *Then* you might move to a templated solution:

Starting with an `is_duration` template is not a bad place to start.  Even if you end up not using it for this project, it might be handy in another:

```
template <class T>
struct is_duration
    : public std::false_type
    {};

template <class Rep, class Period>
struct is_duration<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>
    : public std::true_type
    {};
```

Now you can say `is_duration<T>{}` and this is a compile-time bool which will answer either true of false.  You could use this (for example) like this:

```
template <class D,
          class = std::enable_if_t<is_duration<D>{}>>
class myTimer
{
    D time_;
};
```

This will make instantiations on anything but `std::chrono::duration` fail to compile.

You could also take this approach which doesn't require `is_duration`:

```
template <class D> class myTimer;

template <class Rep, class Period>
class myTimer<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>
{
};
```

If interested in exploring this route, try both ways and decide which error message you like best.

And don't forget:  The best solution for you may be the easiest:  Just use `nanoseconds` and make everything concrete on that.

Comment: I could use nanoseconds and just have the get methods return based on ratio to get hours etc... I guess my goal was to make a timer that would track either hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc... based on what the dev chooses as a typename when defining the class object. Though I may be overcomplicating it.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose class over template?

Comment: @TravisTruttschel:  I'm not sure I understand your question.  I tried to cast things as similar to your question as I could, and presented a range of solutions ranging from a non-templated class to class templates.